# How to change the player color by pressing a button?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I want to create a button and if I press it, the color of the player change to the same color of the button.

The problem is that when I tap the screen it plays the action, and I only want to play the action if the player press the button(in this case another `SKSpriteNode`)

```
 class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var circuloPrincipal = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circulo")

    var colorVerde: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.7, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.9)

    var circuloVerde = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fondoBaseBlanco.png")




 for touch in touches {
            let location = circuloVerde

            let circuloVer = circuloVerde

           circuloVerde.position = circuloVerde.position

        circuloPrincipal.color = colorVerde 

        //circulo principal = player
        //color verde = green color
        //circulo verde = button

        }
}
```

Comment: This question is too broad, you could put some of your code, it's not clear you want a solution to UIKit or Sprite-kit library, or both, and in what context

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Where do you add this "button"? Is a UIButton? You have a SKScene? Please be more clear..

Comment: yes. I have an SKScene, and is not a button is a SKSpriteNode

Comment: Well ok, now I can analize your question..

Comment: Welcome to SO Diego, the thanks to the users come with votes or by flag the answer as the correct answer for the thread. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your button add a name like this:

```
circuloVerde.name = "button"
```

In the `touchesBegan` delegate method do:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        let touch = touches.first
        let positionInScene = touch!.locationInNode(self)

        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

        if let name = touchedNode.name
        {
           print("name : \(name)")
           if name == "button" {
              //do my stuff 
              circuloPrincipal.color = colorVerde
              // or you can do also
              circuloPrincipal.color = circuloVerde.color 
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Alessandro for you help! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

To get the colour of the button do this.

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    UIColor *btnColor = btn.backgroundColor;
 // Now you can set this btnColor as the color of your player.
}
```